# Express routing outside of server.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I've followed numerous Express/Angular guides so far for routing, and in the scenarios each work, and I've gotten the hang of it but I'm having a slight issue when I try to incorporate the route into -another- JS file.

For instance I put this in server.js, it'll work. If I put it in 'char.js' it won't work.

I'm using a package that allows these functions to pull Blizzard game data. The end-points work directly, but trying to get the functions to work inline.

**server.js** -- The file that npm opens with

```
app.get('/Users', function( req, res){
  return blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: 'Myserver', name: 'Mycharname' })
    .then(response => res.json(response.data))
```

This function will work - If I go to /Users, I will get the json response.

If I move it to

**Chars.js**

```
    const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const account = require('../routes/account');
const wow = require('../routes/wow.js');
const sc2 = require('../routes/sc2');
const d3 = require('../routes/d3');
const blizzard = require('../config/blizzard.js');


/*
// Create a route for the 'Users' path
const char = router.get('Char', function( req, res){
  return blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: 'Myserv', name: 'Myname' })
    .then(response => res.json(response.data))
});
*/



 // Create a route for the 'Users' path
    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: 'Myrealm', name: 'Mychar' })
    .then(response => res.json(response.data));
});

    });



/*
// Create a route for the 'Users' path
const users = router.get('Users', function(req, res) {
  return blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: 'Myserv', name: 'Myname' })
    .then(response => res.json(response.data));
});
*/
module.exports = router;
```

It no longer will work. I have the -same- snipper, but with diff name for the chars variable in my Users controller that is working 100% outside of that function.

I'm unsure exactly what it is I'm missing.

**Entire Server.js**

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config({ silent: true });

var express = require('express')
      ,http = require('http')
      ,path = require('path')
      ,app = express()
      ,fs = require('fs');
const router = express.Router();
const account = require('./routes/account');
const wow = require('./routes/wow');
const sc2 = require('./routes/sc2');
const d3 = require('./routes/d3');
const chars = require('./routes/chars.js');
const blizzard = require('./config/blizzard.js');



const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use('/account', account);
app.use('/wow', wow);
app.use('/sc2', sc2);
app.use('/d3', d3);
// Mount the 'Users' route to `/`
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {  
  res.render('index');
});

app.use('/', chars);


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Blizzard.js Example App listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```

I ran this by the package owner and he stated the code I have in Chars.js should work so I feel like it's something regarding my placement of files, or variables. I did console.log on chars.js and got a response from server.js so I do know it's loading it.

If an additional script is required, let me know. That could also be my issue because I have only been modifying these two scripts.

**Updated code to reflect changes**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create another express instance in `Chars.js`.

1 Remove

```
const app = express()
```

2 Move

```
app.use('/', chars);
```

from `Chars.js` to `Server.js`

working example:

`server.js`

```
'use strict';

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const express = require('express')
      ,http = require('http')
      ,path = require('path')
      ,app = express()
      ,fs = require('fs');

const chars = require('./routes/chars.js');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('index'));
app.use('/', chars);

app.listen(port, () => console.log('online:', port));
```

`routes/chat.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
//       return blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: 'Myrealm', name: 'Mychar' })
//                 .then(response => res.json(response.data));

    setTimeout(function() {
      res.json({data: 'some data'})
    }, 2000);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Added `app.use('/chars.js', chars);` to server.js
Added `app.use('/', char);` to server.js

Now getting 'Router.use() requires middleware. I will look into new error.

Comment: 1 You need to get router instance (in Chars.js)
2 Setup route 
3 export created router
4 in Server.js you should connect it to some path 
  app.use('/', chars);
where `const chars = require('./routes/chars.js');`

this should be enough, remove `app.use('/chars.js', chars);`

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I'm obviously missing something. I've updated my chars.js and server.js - Would you mind telling me what I'm doing wrong? (I added in module.exports as recommended based on that 'Middleware issue'

Comment: After re-reading your statement numerous times, I found that replacing my 'const users = `router.get(Users)'` function with 
`router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    return blizzard.wow.character(['profile'], { origin: 'us', realm: 'Myserv', name: 'Myname' })
    .then(response => res.json(response.data));
});
` was able to resolve the issue.

What is it that was off about the const users section that makes it not work? I left it in the code above but commented it out in mine.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Seems you are trying to attach index page handler and chars handler to one route '/'

Comment: Thanks for the support - Both your insight and comments led me to understand more about how to Google my issue, and your example worked in the end also.